# Error: Compile OpenCV 4.4 /usr/bin/ld cannot find -ltrue, cuda 11.1, cudnn 8.0.5 gtx 950m

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, cmake

```
(cv_gpu) hd@hd-pc:~/Documents/cv_gpu/opencv/build$ make -j4 \
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig \
[  1%] Built target libjasper \
[  2%] Built target ippiw \
[  3%] Built target quirc \
[  3%] Built target ittnotify \
[  6%] Built target IlmImf \
[  7%] Built target ade \
[  7%] Built target opencv_videoio_plugins \
[  7%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.so \
[  9%] Built target libprotobuf \
[  9%] Built target numeric \
[  9%] Built target gen_opencv_python_source
Scanning dependencies of target multiview \
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltrue \
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status \
modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.4.0' failed \
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.4.0] Error 1 \
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2930: recipe for target 'modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/all' failed
```

I can't find anything related to this library, please give me a hint
I try to use openCV 4.4 with cuda 11.1 cudnn v8.0.5 on gtx 950m

And this is my cmake command:

```
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-6 \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.1 \
    -D CUDA_nppicom_LIBRARY=true \
    -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
    -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
    -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=5.0 \
    -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
    -D WITH_WEBP=OFF \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D WITH_QT=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
    -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Documents/cv_gpu/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

The result of cmake command:

```
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.1, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             50
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.0.5)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/hd/Documents/cv_gpu/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/hd/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.9)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
--     numpy:                       /home/hd/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.4)
--     install path:                /home/hd/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/hd/.virtualenvs/cv_gpu/bin/python3
--     Pylint:                      /home/hd/.local/bin/pylint (ver: 3.6.9, checks: 179)
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
```

I recognize it still used gcc-7 though i chose gcc-6 at the second row
I try searching many pages but can't get the answer

Comment: have you tried as mentioned in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229774/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc ?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaqgH.png)

add ocv_list_filterout(CUDA_npp_LIBRARY "true") in OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).